# Firebase emulator triggers do not show any logged output

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I am using firebase local emulators for my cloud functions, firestore and realtime database on which I run unit tests using Jest. Whenever I run a test and data is written to my emulated firestore, a trigger gets fired. There is no output of which triggers got fired in the console. Also, within those triggers I am using `console.log()` for example to print relevant information. However this doesn't get printed in the terminal either.
Does anyone know how get information of triggered functions and logged output to the console?

Thanks

Comment: If the emulator suite doesn't do what you want, I suggest opening an issue on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: ok so there is nothing at the moment? That makes it not very useful for testing..

Comment: I don't know - I suggest filing the issue so you can get a response from someone who does.